# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Ves_Tempcp_Helper_Framework' not found in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento Framework. I've just downloaded theme and followed all the steps to install it in Magento. But its showing me the below error when I tried to load my home page.

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Ves_Tempcp_Helper_Framework' not found in C:\wamp\www\dummysite\app\Mage.php on line 547
```

Need Help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already try clearing Magento’s cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some problem with theme and it is missing the helper file. Make sure the file exists in

> app/code/community/Ves/Tempcp/Helper/Framework.php

or

> app/code/local/Ves/Tempcp/Helper/Framework.php
>   Also reupload all your theme files to make sure none of them are missing. 
>   Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. There is no Ves folder in my app/code/community/ . I am trying to reupload all my theme files now.